# How to order/sort a list where multiple users insert into different positions in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql

Using: PHP, MySQL

Case: users can add/edit/delete categories in a news system. There is one main user which can also add/edit/delete categories. Categories added by the main user will also be displayed in the category list of the "basic" users. A "basic" user should be able to add categories and change the position of his categories and the categories of the main user so he can create his own category list.

Right now i have these tables (basic example):

```
table: users {
               id,
               name
             }

table: categories 
             {
                id,
                user_id,
                title,
                position
              }
```

When displaying the list on the page of a "basic" user i would something like this:

```
 SELECT title 
 FROM categories 
 WHERE user_id = #BASIC_USER_ID OR user_id = #MAIN_USER_ID 
 ORDER BY position
```

How can i make it so a "basic" user can create his own sort order using the position column. Do i need different columns/tables? Don't forget that categories could be shared over hundreds of users so when adding a new category as the main user i don't want to update hundreds of tables so all the "basic" users also have the category in their list. It should be on the fly maintaining positions etc.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: so will a basic user's categories always be a subset of a main user's categories, or will both type of users contain all the same categories but just with different order? Also, are all basic users associated to only one main user?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to:

use the position column to set an INT value to represent its order, and that only "basic users" results should use this in the query?

if so you could add a condition in a $var to your SQL query...

```
$orderQ = (BASIC_USER_ID !=false) ? "ORDER BY position" : "";

SELECT title FROM categories WHERE user_id = BASIC_USER_ID OR user_id = MAIN_USER_ID $orderQ
```

something like that could work..

however if you want each user to have their own unique sort, I would add a new table:

user_id,position,item_id

use that table to determine the sort values for the user, if blank, revert to default values maybe.

```
table: users {
           id,
           name
         }

table: categories 
         {
            id,
            user_id,
            title,
            position     // revert to for default
          }
table: positions 
         {
           user_id,
           position,
           category_id
         }
```

if you want to allow more than just the position, why duplicate more of the category table and use it to store the personal references to the categories table; extend the position table to include the users title choice etc....

Answer (score 0):

Tables:

user:

```
+-------+----------------------+
| id    | name                 |
+-------+----------------------+
| 1     | "Admin"              |
+-------+----------------------+
| 2     | "Blue User"          |
+-------+----------------------+
| 3     | "Red User"           |
+-------+----------------------+
```

category:

```
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| id    | title                | created_by  |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| 1     | "Category 1"         |      1      |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| 2     | "Category 2"         |      1      |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| 3     | "Category 3"         |      1      |
+-------+----------------------+-------------+
```

user_category:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
| user_id | category_id  | position  | custom_title       |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    1    |      1       |     1     |  NULL              |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    1    |      2       |     2     |  NULL              |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    1    |      3       |     3     |  NULL              |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    2    |      1       |     3     |  "Red Category 1"  |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    2    |      2       |     2     |  "Red Category 2"  |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    2    |      3       |     1     |  "Red Category 3"  |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+    
|    3    |      1       |     2     |  "Blue Category 1" |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    3    |      2       |     1     |  "Blue Category 2" |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    3    |      3       |     3     |  "Blue Category 3" |
+---------+--------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Select categories for a user:

```
select c.title, uc.custom_title from category c join user_category uc on c.category_id=uc.category_id where uc.user_id= ? order by uc.position
```

If uc.custom_title is not null then display that title, otherwise display c.title.

Answer (score 0):

The position story is what i had in mind but i still had a problem when the main user would add new categories. The sub-user didn't position the item yet and i don't want to update hundreds of rows. I now solved this position problem using this MySQL function:

```
IFNULL(subuser_position, default_position) AS position_temp
```

Falling back on the default_position if the subuser_position is NULL